# Apply Change is gry(is off) in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, viewbinding

With respect
I upgraded from 3.18 thread to Grifa thread while running the button project
Cinch app is turned off. But I didn't have this problem in the previous thread.
That's why I went back to my previous state. I followed all the protocols, including installing the SDK, matching Gridel, and even the internal settings, and I should mention that I use Knox instead of the internal emulator, and I don't have this problem with the physical phone. I also tried 24|29|33 thread, but I didn't get the result in Grifa thread. I would be grateful if anyone could share their experience in this field with me personally! I am also posting the griddle module and project thread to better explain my problem. I only have this problem in Grifa thread and I even updated Gridel and set the Gridel API according to the standard, but I still didn't get the result and I have to use the current thread.

```
With respect
I upgraded from 3.18 thread to Grifa thread while running the button project
Cinch app is turned off. But I didn't have this problem in the previous thread.
That's why I went back to my previous state. I followed all the protocols, including installing the SDK, matching Gridel, and even the internal settings, and I should mention that I use Knox instead of the internal emulator, and I don't have this problem with the physical phone. I also tried 24|29|33 thread, but I didn't get the result in Grifa thread. I would be grateful if anyone could share their experience in this field with me personally! I am also posting the griddle module and project thread to better explain my problem. I only have this problem in Grifa thread and I even updated Gridel and set the Gridel API according to the standard, but I still didn't get the result and I have to use the current thread. I no longer have to add them manually every time I create a project. Thanks Sam
```